# ClaiR/Rascal: Best way to list public functions?

Tags: class, header, rascal, public-method, clair

I am parsing an C++ header file using ClaiR and want to get a list of the public functions.

```
visit(ast) {
    case \class(_, name(n), _, decs): {
        println("class name: <n>");
        isPublic = true;
        for (dec <- decs) {
            switch(dec) {
                case \visibilityLabel(\public()): {
                    println("Public functions");
                    isPublic = true;
                }
                case \visibilityLabel(\protected()): {
                    println("Protected functions");
                    isPublic = false;
                }
                case \visibilityLabel(\private()): {
                    println("Private functions");
                    isPublic = false;
                }
                case \simpleDeclaration(_, [\functionDeclarator([*_], [*_], name(na), [*_], [*_])]): {
                    if (isPublic) {
                        println("public function: <na>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works. But is there a better (smaller) way of acquiring the public functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an M3 `modifiers` relation which might have the info you're looking for:

- https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/1514b30341525fe66cf99a64ed995052293f09d5/src/org/rascalmpl/library/analysis/m3/Core.rsc#L61
- that relation can be composed with the `o` operator with the qualified names of your methods to see which modifiers are declared on which method

However, that relation must be extracted of course. Perhaps that still needs to be added to ClaiR?

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the public/protected/private access modifiers aren't proper "modifiers" on declarations; instead, all member declarations following an access modifier (up to a possible next access modifier) have the declared visiblity (in your example, the second `public:` also makes `myFunc4` public). It would be straightforward to implement an AST traversal to obtain members' visiblity information and add it to a new M3 table, though. Your suggestion of `public void myFunc5();` is invalid syntax.

The `ProblemType` in the decl indicates that the first argument of the `myFunc` method is unresolved (likely due to a missing import). The `toString` of this `ProblemType` in the type information should not be there, though, that is a bug.

Comment: Aha, this response is more of an answer to your answer below. Something along the lines of the traversal in your question seems reasonable.

Comment: If it is inline with M3 format/contents, it would be nice to have the visibility info in it.

Comment: I added a table to ClaiR's M3 containing the visibility information.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code the looks like this:

`MyClass {
  public:
    void myFunc1();
  private:
    void myFunc2();
  public:
    void myFunc3();
    void myFunc4();`

m3.modifiers does not provide public/private information. I guess (have not tried), it will work for `public void myFunc5();`

I also see some strange errors. 
 <|cpp+method:///MyClass/myFunc(org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.ProblemType@38270bb,unsigned.int,unsigned.int)|,virtual()>,
Is this for a type it cannot resolve (include not provided to parser)?

Comment: Ask Rodin to have a look; but yes that looks like a partially unresolved type; a resolved method of an unresolved class?